# how to check if the input text has value without triggering the submit in it by java script only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a kind of effect on input so it works something like this if i focus on the input the label of that input goes up 100px from the input and if one enters the value and unfocused the input it will still remain on the top but if the input is empty and user click outside the input the label will comeback to position again .Help me to achieve this effect thanks.I want to make it like the floating labels.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>

.form{width:600px; margin:auto; }

.input-conatiner{ width:400px; margin:60px auto ; text-align:center; height:35px ;width:320px;  position:relative; }
.input-conatiner input{position:absolute; background:none; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%;  }
.input-conatiner label{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9; transition:300ms ;}
.input-conatiner:hover input + label {color:red; transform:translatey(-150%);}
 
</style>



<body>

<form>

<div class="input-conatiner">
<input type="text"/>
<label>HI there</label>



</div>

<div class="input-conatiner">

<input type="text"/>
<label>HI there</label>



</div>


<div class="input-conatiner">
<input type="text"/>
<label>HI there</label>



</div>



</form>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not easily readable, sorry. Can you add some punctuation? Also, since you didn't include any code, I can't tell if the situation you describe is something you have now, or something you want to achieve.

Comment: sure i have added my code.i want this to be execute on  focus .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and if one enters the value and unfocused the input it will still remain on the top but if the input is empty and user click outside the input the label will comeback to position again

So you only want the label to go down again, if the user did not fill out the field? And if they did fill in something, then it should stay above?

Only way to (halfway) achieve this using CSS only, would be to make the input field `required`, and then use the `:valid` pseudo class:

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>

.form{width:600px; margin:auto; }

.input-conatiner{ width:400px; margin:60px auto ; text-align:center; height:35px ;width:320px;  position:relative; }
.input-conatiner input{position:absolute; background:none; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%;  }
.input-conatiner label{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9; transition:300ms ;}
.input-conatiner:hover input + label,
.input-conatiner input:valid + label {color:red; transform:translatey(-150%);}
</style>
<body>
<form>
<div class="input-conatiner">
<input type="text" required/>
<label>HI there</label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need anything more than that, you might have to use JavaScript.

Comment: yes i want to work this effect properly as i mentioned above please help me to achieve this.